# Deducting 5 hours 30 minutes from the selected date time

Tags: php

I am trying to deduct 5 hours and 30 mins from the selected datetime but it is not working

my php code

```
 $ambulanceDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', ($_POST['ambuStartDate'] . " " . $_POST['ambuStartTime']));
                $date1 = str_replace('-', '/', $ambulanceDate);
                $ambulanceUpdatedDate = date('m-d-Y',strtotime($date1 . "-5 hours 30 minutes"));
                $ambulanceUpdatedDate = new DateTime($ambulanceUpdatedDate);
```

Comment: there is aalready a date time difference api inside `DateTime` class that you can use, just use the php manual

Comment: i tried a lot of ways to make this work but it is failing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you even do `$date1 = str_replace('-', '/', $ambulanceDate);`? Couldn't you just do `date('Y/m/d H:i:s'`...

This should do it:

```
//Change 'Y-m-d H:i:s' with the format of your ambuStartDate, and ambuStartTime.
$ambulanceDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', ($_POST['ambuStartDate'] . " " . $_POST['ambuStartTime']));
$ambulanceUpdatedDate = $ambulanceDate->sub(new DateInterval('P5DT30M'));
//Format it how you like:
$formattedUpdatedDate = $ambulanceUpdatedDate->format('m-d-Y h:iA');
```

See https://eval.in/772578

Comment: isn't it just a comment not answer to his question

Comment: Yeah, I thought I created it as a comment @MASIDDIQUI. I ended up just turning it into an answer.

Comment: sorry not working.. I have this input field where I am showing Indian time and the admin can modify this time so I need to save this time in UTC as that is the standard followed hence I am trying to convert it but your code is not deducting 5 hours 30 mins from the time..

Answer (score 1):

Use `modify` function with `DateTime` [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php):

```
<?php
$ambulanceDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', ($_POST['ambuStartDate'] . " " . $_POST['ambuStartTime']));

$date_time = new DateTime($ambulanceDate);
$date_time->modify('-5 hours');
$date_time->modify('-30 minutes');

$ambulanceUpdatedTime = $date_time->format('m-d-Y H:i:s');

echo $ambulanceDate . PHP_EOL;
echo '-5h 30mins:' . PHP_EOL;
echo $ambulanceUpdatedTime;
```

Output:

```
2017-04-11 05:22:07
-5h 30mins:
04-10-2017 23:52:07
```

Demo here: https://eval.in/772567

Refined since question really wants to convert a local time to UTC time:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
//$ambulanceDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', ($_POST['ambuStartDate'] . " " . $_POST['ambuStartTime']));
$ambulanceDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());

$indian_time = new DateTime($ambulanceDate);
$utc_time = new DateTime($ambulanceDate);

$ambulanceUpdateTime = $utc_time
  ->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'))
  ->format('m-d-Y H:i:s');

echo 'Indian time: ' . $indian_time->format('m-d-Y H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;
echo 'UTC time: ' . $ambulanceUpdateTime;
```

Demo of this: https://eval.in/772648

Comment: sorry not working.. I have this input field where I am showing Indian time and the admin can modify this time so I need to save this time in UTC as that is the standard followed hence I am trying to convert it but your code is not deducting 5 hours 30 mins from the time..

Comment: So the input time is Indian time and you want to save this time as UTC?

Comment: @DhavalChheda I updated answer to convert timezones using the API rather than subtract 5h 30 mins.